# How to select a column in Visual Studio Code on Linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I believe that column select (vertical select) is alt+drag on Windows, but can't find how to do it on Linux.

Comment: Have you checked in the Default Keyboard Shortcuts within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I see things like this `cursorColumnSelectLeft`, but no general or mouse select key

Answer (score 3):

Seems that there isn't such feature in visual studio code.
But there's a feature called `multiple cursors` which is supposedly more powerful than `column selection`. so here's how to use it:

- `ctrl+alt+up/down` to create multiple cursors.
- hold `shift` then use `left/right` to select text block.

ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1515

Comment: Actually you press `ctrl+alt+shift+up/down` to create multiple cursor first, then press `left/right` for text block selection

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu 20.04 its
`alt+shift+up/down`

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 as well